# The meaning of the stress-energy-momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, definition, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I just learned some General Relativity and have a couple of questions about the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) $T$.

In what follows, please let’s suppose that General Relativity and the Standard Model of particle physics are pretty much correct.

1. Does $T$ include contributions from all the forces, or only gravity?
2. Is it possible for a hypothetical universe to have the same laws of physics as our actual universe, and the same $T$ tensor throughout spacetime as our actual universe, and yet be physically different than our actual universe in some way? If yes, in what way could it be different? If no, is it fair to say that $T$ “encodes” all of the physical information?

Comment: T contains everything NOT gravitational.

Comment: $T^{\mu\nu}$ encodes only the density and flow of non-gravitational energy and momentum, and not any other information. That energy and momentum could be due to atoms, or neutrinos, or photons, etc. Normally one first encounters the energy-momentum tensor when learning relativistic mechanics or electromagnetism. When you see it in GR, you’re supposed to think, “Oh, that thing again”.

Comment: What you really need is not the coordinate dependend $T_{\mu \nu}$ nor $T^{\mu \nu}$ but the mixed $T_{\mu}^{\nu}$, that gives you the energy density and pressure. In cartesian flat Minkowski the covariant, contravariant and mixed ones are the same, but generally they are not.

Comment: @Yukterez The mixed version is still coordinate dependent. To get the energy and pressure measured by an observer you need to contract with the observers frame vectors.